# Django - multiple static file directories javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, subdirectory

I have a Django project consisting of 3 apps - Survey, Django-admin and Chartsjs (installed through nodejs). The directory structure is:

- Project

  - survey/ (urls, admin...)

    - views/

      - **analytics_view.py**
    - models/
    - static/
    - templates/

      - survey

        - **analytics.html**
    - ...etc/
  - **Bootstrap_admin/**

    - **static/**
    - admin/

      - css/
    - boostrap_admin

      - img/
      - js/
    - templates/
    - ...etc
  - node_modules

    - chart.js/

      - dist/

        - **Chart.js**
    - chartjs-color/
    - ....etc/

When I built Boostrap-Admin, I was left with the following in my settings.py file:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/bootstrap_admin/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT, 'static')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.normpath(os.path.join(ROOT, '..', "survey", "static")),
```

In analytics_view.py I have a class:

```
class AnalyticsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "survey/analytics.html"
```

And in analytics.html I have the code example provided by chartsjs:

```
{% block extrahead %}
<script src="../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Between here \/</p>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<p>and here /\ is a graph</p>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I've hard coded the script source (I know you aren't meant to do that, but I was trying to get it to display *something* to make sure it's working before I redo it).

When I go to 127.0.0.1/survey/analytics, I can see the text and the canvas - but there are no graphs displayed.

In my console I can see

```
"GET /node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2250
```

So the script pointing to the correct source, but it's just not picking up the JS file as a JS file.

I've tried setting the STATIC_URL to the root directory and using STATICFILES_DIRS to specify the other apps' static directories (tried both these guides [1](http://blog.xjtian.com/post/52685286308/serving-static-files-in-django-more-complicated), [2](https://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/django-and-static-files/) with no luck).

I know Django isn't picking up the javascript files from the correct directories, but currently hopelessly lost as to how to fix this (I'm sure it's to do with the STATICFILES_DIRS but can't find a solution that works, and the documentation/youtubers don't really explain how to do this for multiple app directories very well)

Comment: Have you fired collectstatic command? In general this should without specifying explicitly but only adding in static folder of each app.

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome, open Developer console and go to `Sources`, then check if the `static` folder contains your `javascript` files.If not, try pressing `Ctrl` + `F5` to clear cache, django requires cache clear after making changes to the `static` folder

Comment: @EnricoLund did as you suggested. There's no Javascript files in the static folder. In the console, I have the error: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js net::ERR_ABORTED